# Switch between two html templates based on condition in backbone js views

Tags: html, templates, laravel-5, backbone.js, view

Im new to backbone js... I have an application where i need to switch between two different html templates in backbone view. How should i define those template in a single view and render function on that template based on my condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can render two different templates in the following way

```
                                    <div>
                                        <%if(condition){%>>
                                              <div>Template 1</div>
                                        <%}else{%>
                                             Template 2
                                                <%}%>
                                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var PersonView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',

    template_1: _.template("<strong><%= name_1 %></strong> (<%= age_1 %>) - <%= occupation_1 %>"),
    template_2: _.template("<strong><%= name_2 %></strong> (<%= age_2 %>) - <%= occupation_2 %>"),
    initialize: function(){
        this.render();
    },

    render: function(){
        if (condition) {
          this.$el.html( this.template_1(this.model.toJSON()));
        } else {
            this.$el.html( this.template_2(this.model.toJSON()));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @anu-prabha Please check